# Is there a way to chain multiple if-let statements using the same variable name?

Tags: swift

Let's say I have three optional strings, `string1`, `string2`, and `string3`. I don't know which, if any, is not `nil` so I am using `if-let` statements, and then I want to do something with that non-nil String regardless of which one it is.

Right now, this works in Swift but is cumbersome:

```
if let newString = string1 {
   doSomething()
} else if let newString = string2 {
   doSomething()
} else if let newString = string3 {
   doSomething()
}
```

Can I do something similar to this (which gives me an error):

```
if let newString = string1 || let newString = string2 || let newString = string3 {
   doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Could you pack those in an array?

Comment: put them in an array and use `if let newString = [string1,string2, string3].compactMap({$0}).first {`

Comment: Since you don't seem to need `newString`, why not `if string1 != nil || string2 != nil || string3 != nil { doSomething() }`.

Answer (score 7):

**Solution 1** :

```
if let newString = [string1, string2, string3].compactMap({$0}).first {
    print(newString)
}
```

The `compactMap` function will generate an array of non-null values and you'll be taking the `first` value of it

**Solution 2** :

```
if let newString = [string1, string2, string3].first(where: {$0 != nil}) {
  print(newString)
}
```

Note: As suggested by @Connor and the brilliant solutions by @vacawama, the above solution would generate a double optional ( The first optional coming from the array of optionals and then the `first` function contributing to the second optional). This can be fixed by either:

1. `if let newString = [str1, str2, str3].first(where: {$0 != nil}) as? String {`
2. `if let newString = [str1, str2, str3].first(where: {$0 != nil}) ?? nil {`
3. `if case let newString?? = [str1, str2, str3].first(where: {$0 != nil}) {`
4. `if let first = [str1, str2, str3].first(where: { $0 != nil }), let newString = first`

**Solution 3** :

(This won't scale and quite frankly is pretty weird)

```
if let newString = string1 ?? string2 ?? string3 {
   print(newString)
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that in the second code block, `newString` is still an optional. The type of `[string1, string2, string3].first(where: {$0 != nil})` is `String??`, and the `if let` will only unwrap one layer.

Comment: You can fix that with `if let newString = [str1, str2, str3].first(where: {$0 != nil}) as? String {`

Comment: or with `if let newString = [str1, str2, str3].first(where: {$0 != nil}) ?? nil {`

Comment: or with `if case let newString?? = [str1, str2, str3].first(where: {$0 != nil}) {`

Comment: or with `if let first = [str1, str2, str3].first(where: { $0 != nil }), let newString = first {`

Comment: What's the purpose of the `{$0}` in the first solution?

Comment: @Kevin2566 `{$0}` is the closure passed to `compactMap` that tells it to return only those elements from the array which are non-nil.

Answer (score 1):

@MayRestinPeace has 3 great answers.  Here's one that uses `switch` pattern matching and tuple matching to unwrap and bind the first non-nil String:

```
switch (string1, string2, string3) {
case (let newString?, _, _), (_, let newString?, _), (_, _, let newString?):
    print(newString)
default:
    print("alas! they're all nil")
}
```